# SocketTimeoutException using URLFetch to a service that sends channel messages

Tags: java, google-app-engine, urlfetch, channel-api, socket-timeout-exception

We have two AppEngine (Java) apps. One of them uses URLFetch to the other to create an appointment. In the receiver, we've added a feature where we use the Channel API to see if there are any open channels and let them know about the new data.

The URLFetch call is failing with a SocketTimeoutException. All the code in the receiver is executed (including all open channels being notified) but the calling app still gets a SocketTimeoutException. When I comment out the channel notification line, no error.

This happens only in the deployed app, not in dev mode. Also, the call doesn't come close to reaching the 60-second (or even the old 10-second) timeout allowed by URLFetch.

Comment: We can't possibly help without seeing the code and the stacktrace.

Comment: I'd put together a sample but we've worked around it. Instead of notifying channels directly, we're sending the request to a task queue. This queue does the same thing but doesn't return the SocketTimeoutException. In any case, the original was just a standard servlet with a call to ChannelServiceFactory.getChannelService( ).sendMessage at the end.

Comment: It has to be something specific to your app - it's definitely not the case that it's impossible to make a urlfetch from one app to another!

Comment: Agreed. And we're doing it regularly. The error occurs only if we make a Channel API call in the receiving app.

Answer (score 0):

The default deadline for urlfetch is 5s, so if your application take more than 5s to load and execute the handler it will return a `SocketTimeoutException`.

As described in the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/urlfetch/overview#Requests), you can set a longer deadline for your urlfetch call using `setConnectTimeout` or `setReadTimeout`

In addition, it is a good idea to move the api call that can be deferred (i.e not necessary to build the http response) to a [task queue](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/taskqueue/):

- the deadline for task queue request is longer (10 minutes, instead of 60s)
- the task will be retried if failing
- urlfetch timeout is longer too (10 minutes)